# List all files with length of name between 3 and 6 characters

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh

I have to write a little shell script for class, and since there's only online lectures I do not have the option to ask my professor for help.

The task (should be) is actually very simple:

> Write a shell script which lists all files in the current directory, whose name is **greater than 3** and **smaller than 6** characters
>
> - `12.txt` --> should **not** be listed
> - `123.txt` --> should be **not** listed
> - `1234567.txt` --> should **not** be listed
> - `12345.txt` --> should be listed
> - `123456.txt` --> should be listed

The suffix (filename extension) `.txt` is not given in the question, its just an example by me. The listing of all files should work for any suffix.

I would be happy if anyone could help me understand the correct commands for this, or maybe post a link to a tutorial etc.

Comment: If bash specific solutions are allowed, use globbing: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html

Comment: In normal Unix terminology, the first name has 6 characters — the `.txt` is part of the name too.  You say 'greater than 3 and smaller than 6' — that means "4 or 5" usually.  However, your examples suggest "the basename of the file (minus extension) is 3-6 characters long".  It helps to be clear.  Presumably `123456.c` should be printed?  Or are you only interested in `.txt` files?  What to so with `12.34.56.txt`?  And `12.34.txt`? Is `printf '%s\n' ???.txt ????.txt ?????.txt ??????.txt` a solution?

Comment: Doe the prof offer any Q&A video sessions (single or group)? Does the prof have an email address? What's the expected answer for a file with a name like `mydb.log.20200520.0815` or `daily_data.20200520.txt`?

Comment: @ markp-fuso   expected answers for you examples would be, to not list them, since the names are longer than 6 characters. btw the suffix .txt is not given, that was just an example...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler exactly, you grasped what i was looking for. i meant only the basename. and no, it should work for any type of filename i just used the .txt as an example.

Comment: @sepæpa did you change the question many times?

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh i just added the detail, that it should work for any type of file and only filter by the length of basename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shopt -s extglob
ls ??@(?|??|???|????).* 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

From the example you gave, I deduce that you want to list all file whose **base** name after removing the suffix `.*` is 3 to 6 chars, I would simply do:

```
ls ??{?,??,???,????}.* 2> /dev/null
```

Edited: I added the redirection to `/dev/null` for avoiding an error message, as result of a comment below and as suggested by others.

Assuming your directory contains next files:

```
1234567.txt
123456.txt
12345.txt
1234.txt
123.txt
12.txt
```

The output will be:

```
123456.txt  12345.txt  1234.txt  123.txt
```

Explanation: `?` matches any character, `{a,b}` matches `a` or `b`. So `{?,??}` matches any sequence of one or two characters. Just extrapolate this to your case: 3 to 6 chars is the same as 2 chars followed by 1, 2, 3 or 4 chars.

Comment: The problem is, it doesnt work unless all of those files exist. it has to work even if there's only a single file, i.e. 1234.txt

Thank you anyways, for your help! :D maybe i should be more detailed

Comment: Could also use `nullglob` instead of redirecting error.

Comment: Using `shopt-s nullglob` avoids errors and unexpanded names.

Answer (score 2):

It's not efficient, but it will help you to understand, looping over each .txt file in the directory and filter them one by one:

```
cd yourpath/dir
for i in *.txt;
do
    new_Val="${i%.*}"
    if (( ${#new_Val} >3 && ${#new_Val} <6 ));
    then
        echo "${i}"
    fi
done
```

remove suffix `.txt` : `${i%.*}`

Length of name : `${#new_Val}`

input :

```
1234567.txt
12345.txt
123aaaa.txt
123aa.txt
1234.txt
```

Output :

```
12345.txt
123aa.txt
1234.txt
```

Comment: You could drop the calculation of `newVal`. Since by construction `i` ends in `.txt`, you can compare the length of `i` to 7 and 10 instead.

Answer (score 2):

In `zsh`, its just

```
setopt extended_glob
print -l ?(#c4,5).*
```

The pattern `?(#c4,5)` matches 4 or 5 characters.